# How to move a $d/dt$ inside a triple integral?

Tags: derivatives, integration, calculus

I faced some equations while reading current density.
$$\iint_S \vec J.d \vec S = - \frac{d}{dt} \iiint_V \rho.dV.$$
And then
$$\iint_S \vec J.d\vec S = -\iiint_V \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}dV. $$
I want to ask that is it always true, or it has some rules and things to keep in mind when moving $\frac{d}{dt}$ into the integral.

Comment: If everything is smooth you're fine. If the volume changes with time, you'll need the lie derivative and some differential forms chops.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the integration limits in $\iiint_V$ don't depend on time it's generally fine.